# Nashorn gives error with Array.from(string)

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, nashorn

I have a javascript file fun.js

```
function fun1(){
    var str='apple';
    var charArray = Array.from(str);
    return charArray;
}
```

I return this charArray to my java code using nashorn. But nashorn gives exception as-

javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Array.from is not a function in  at line number 25

**How can I use Array.from() with nashorn or is there any way to convert string to charArray in js which is compatible with nashorn.**

my java code is -

```
    System.out.println("intialising parser....");

    ScriptEngine engine= new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");

    engine.eval(new FileReader("index.js"));
    Invocable invocable= (Invocable) engine;

    Object obj = (Object)invocable.invokeFunction("fun1");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later I found it was simple like this-

```
function fun1(){
var str='apple';
var charArray =str.split('');
return charArray;
}
```

Also it is compatible with nashorn.

Answer (score 1):

There is, it is `String.toCharArray()`, because Nashorn allows you to use Java methods. So you can do,

```
System.out.println("initializing parser....");
String js = "function fun1() { return 'apple'.toCharArray() }";
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
try {
    engine.eval(js);
    Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;

    Object obj = (Object) invocable.invokeFunction("fun1");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString((char[]) obj));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And that outputs

```
initializing parser....
[a, p, p, l, e]
```

Comment: This might be correct but in my case split('') was working.Thanks for your response

Comment: split("") would create N strings with single character in it. Calling toCharArray is definitely efficient - as that one creates actual Java char[]